# How to do a JOIN and write a column in the same statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

If I had two tables like:

```
first          second

a | b | c       b | d
----------      -----
1 | 2 |         2 | 4
2 | 3 |         3 | 5
```

and I wanted to update table `first` so that it writes column `c` to be column `a` * column `d`, how would I do this in a single query?

I'd want something like these two statements combined:

```
SELECT * FROM first LEFT OUTER JOIN second on first.b=second.b
```

and

```
UPDATE first SET c = (b * d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** I am not sure about `syntax` of `SQLLITE` but you can use one of the following with `INNER JOIN`

```
--MYSQL
UPDATE test1 t1
INNER JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.b = t2.b
SET t1.c = t1.a*t2.d 

--SQL-SERVER
UPDATE t1 SET t1.c = t1.a*t2.d
FROM test1 t1
INNER JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.b = t2.b
```

It Should work for `SQLLITE`

```
UPDATE test1 SET test1.c = test1.a *
(SELECT d FROM test2 WHERE test2.b = test1.b)
```

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.

Comment: I hope, my updated answer should work. Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE     
  first
SET
  first.c = second.d
FROM     
  first INNER JOIN second ON first.d= second.d
```

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

This might be of some use (for oracle):

```
update first t1
set t1.c =
( Select t1.b*t2.d
from second t2
where t1.b = t2.b);
```

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.

Comment: Does the question mention SQLite anywhere ?

Comment: Yes, in the tags.

Comment: my bad..missed it likely